# Magento 2 subscription products approach

Tags: magento2, custom-options, simple-product, tierprice, subscription

I am working with the subscription related product, consider the following scenario.we are having two customer group like C1 and C2. then having the product P1, the price of the product will vary based on the customer group also based on the plan(Monthly,Yearly)

**See the price below**
[image]

If the C1 group customer logged in means, we will show the two plan

- Monthly : 100
- Yearly : 1000

The customer select any one of the subscription and added to the cart.

how can i achieve the above logic, i have two things in mind

1. Override custom option and add the subscription plan
2. Override tier-price and add the subscription plan

Which one is the suitable for accomplish the above logic and share any link how to achieve in Magento2 code

Note : I am working with the simple products